# SQL Server Management Tools available on SQL Server 2012 express?

Tags: sql-server, installation, sql-server-2012

My goal is to access a server with some cube data and query it.  If I understand correctly  I need `Analysis Services` in order to accomplish this.

[image: Analysis Services greyed out]

My Current install of SQL Server Management Studio as shown above does not have Analysis Services available.

When I install SQL Server 2012 express the following are the only options I have, I'm not seeing an option for management tools complete.

[image: Only three options]

Is this because Analysis Services are not available in the express version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you only get the database engine (and a bit of Integration services as it relates to the database engine) with Express.  If you want to connect to SSAS you'll need the non Express version of SSMS.

Check the [**Feature comparison by edition.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx#SSAS)

Comment: Thanks I had looked through the feature comparison page before but I couldn't quite Identify exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for the clarification.